# How to turn off Twig debugging for a views feed?

Tags: 8, debugging

I am trying to build a calendar rss feed from views. The rss.xml is being generated, but it doesn't appear to be accepted as a calendar rss on local systems.

When I look at the source, I see it's shot through with theme debugging comments.

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'views_view_rss' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/modules/views/templates/views-view-rss.html.twig' -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
...
```

Worryingly, I'm also getting escaped angle brackets in some places:

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'views_view_row_rss' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/modules/views/templates/views-view-row-rss.html.twig' -->
<item>
...
&lt;!-- THEME DEBUG --&gt;
&lt;!-- THEME HOOK: &#039;ds_entity_view&#039; --&gt;
&lt;!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from &#039;modules/contrib/ds/templates/ds-entity-view.html.twig&#039; --&gt;
...
```

I'm not an expert on the theming system. I googled for how to turn off theme debugging, but I used drush to issue this command:

```
$ drush state-set theme.debug 0
$ drush @local sget theme.debug
0
$ drush @local cr
Cache rebuild complete.
```

However I am still getting the theme debugging comments in my rss.xml.

How do I disable theme debugging?

**Edit** I looked at my `/sites/default/services.yml`

```
39   twig.config:
40     # Twig debugging:
41     #
42     # When debugging is enabled:
43     # - The markup of each Twig template is surrounded by HTML comments that
44     #   contain theming information, such as template file name suggestions.
45     # - Note that this debugging markup will cause automated tests that directly
46     #   check rendered HTML to fail. When running automated tests, 'debug'
47     #   should be set to FALSE.
48     # - The dump() function can be used in Twig templates to output information
49     #   about template variables.
50     # - Twig templates are automatically recompiled whenever the source code
51     #   changes (see auto_reload below).
52     #
53     # For more information about debugging Twig templates, see
54     # https://www.drupal.org/node/1906392.
55     #
56     # Not recommended in production environments
57     # @default false
58     debug: false
```

This doesn't seem to be the issue, unless I misunderstood or misread.

**Edit 2** Following the advice in the comments, I've made the following edits in my configuration:

- set `cache: false` in `sites/default/services.yml`
- set `debug: false` in `sites/development.services.yml`
- commented out the line loading `/services.yml` in `/sites/default/settings.php`

Here are the changes:

```
 $ git diff

diff --git a/sites/default/services.yml b/sites/default/services.yml
index c6c9e71b9..be755d7a1 100644
--- a/sites/default/services.yml
+++ b/sites/default/services.yml
@@ -75,7 +75,7 @@ parameters:
     #
     # Not recommended in production environments
     # @default true
-    cache: true
+    cache: false
   renderer.config:
     # Renderer required cache contexts:
     #
diff --git a/sites/default/settings.php b/sites/default/settings.php
index 04b8a66e2..a61098d01 100644
--- a/sites/default/settings.php
+++ b/sites/default/settings.php
@@ -3,7 +3,7 @@
 /**
  * Load services definition file.
  */
-$settings['container_yamls'][] = __DIR__ . '/services.yml';
+# $settings['container_yamls'][] = __DIR__ . '/services.yml';

 /**
  * Include the Pantheon-specific settings file.
diff --git a/sites/development.services.yml b/sites/development.services.yml
index 0553016c1..bdf4461b9 100644
--- a/sites/development.services.yml
+++ b/sites/development.services.yml
@@ -5,7 +5,7 @@
 parameters:
   http.response.debug_cacheability_headers: true
   twig.config:
-    debug: true
+    debug: false
     auto_reload: true
     cache: false
 services:
```

And of course, I've done a cache rebuild. I also decided to do a fresh backport, just in case. But, I'm still getting the debugging comments. Here's a partial screenshot of the views preview:

[image]

**Edit** It turns out, I didn't have `development.services.yml` in my `settings.php` (I had commented out a line loading a different yaml file).

```
$ grep development.services.yml settings.php

$
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's all documented in the docs @see https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates

Comment: @leymannx Please see my question update; I looked in `services.yml`, theme debugging is set to false, apparently.

Comment: And `sites/development.services.yml`?

Comment: @leymannx I did a `ctrl-f`, and did not find that in the documentation page you linked. I understand that you are trying to resolve my issue; at the same time your follow-up seems to be an argument for keeping the question open.

Comment: Then please have a look at this other page in the docs: https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914

Comment: Does on of your `settings.php` files have `$settings['container_yamls'][] = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/development.services.yml';` in it? This line should be commented out in production.

Comment: The underlying question is: How did you enable it in the first place?

Comment: @leymannx I didn't. I didn't build this site. I inherited it.

Comment: There are probably a bunch of places you could force that, but development.services.yml is the most common if it's not happening in services.yml

Comment: @Clive I seem to have ruled out `development.services.yml` (see edits), where else might I look?

Comment: It's difficult to say - as far as I know services.yml is the only "official" place to put that config, but if it's not that, and overriding it with Drush doesn't work, it suggests something else is overriding it elsewhere during the page load. Could be a sanctioned method I'm not aware of, or could be a hack job. I'd need to be in front of it to advise deeper than that I'm afraid. By the way you've removed the wrong line from settings.php, `services.yml` needs to be loaded. It's `development.services.yml` that shouldn't be loaded in production if you have it anywhere

Comment: Just to rule it out, open the dev tools in your browser, go to the network tab, disable the cache, and try again. Browsers tend to be very aggressive with caching these days, and you might be seeing stale data

Comment: Isn't this the same issue as https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2672656 ?

Comment: I think the issue here is slightly different @cchen. The OP doesn't seem to be able to remove the comments at all, even though debug mode is (ostensibly) disabled

Comment: @cchen I don't think so -- in that question, the user seems to want to remove debugging comments from just a single field, while I want to remove all debugging comments from an entire rss.xml

Comment: @Clive I understand that it's difficult to say where the code or setting is to *initiate* the adding of twig debugging comments, but isn't there only one place (or pipeline) where Drupal actually adds them during render? Could I get in to that part (even with debugging prints) and then work backwards to see what the cause is?

Comment: Indeed, that's line 76 of core/themes/engines/twig/twig.engine